# Uploading Laravel Project To Godaddy Subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I am trying to upload a project I built following a Laravel tutorial. I have a cpanel account with shared hosting with Godaddy. My portfolio is in the public_html folder so I'm trying upload the project to a subfolder. I've created a directory on the same level as the public_html to hold the laravel files and I've created a subdirectory in the public_html folder with the files from the public folder. If I go the home page the application comes up. Here's a link to the project http://thetravisdavis.com/lsapp/

I'm able to see the homepage of the project but I'm getting Internal Server Error when I try to visit any other pages like http://thetravisdavis.com/lsapp/about

This is my .htaccess file

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lsapp/$1
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've looked at multiple tutorials and similar questions here but most if not all seem to be outdated. Again thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: After a little tinkering with the .htaccess file, I'm no longer getting the Internal server error but Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. it must be something I'm missing in the .htaccess file

Comment: Watch out of shared hosting: http://thetravisdavis.com/lsapp/.env

Answer (score 1):

After a little more googling I found some documentation on what was wrong with my .htaccess file

adding this fixed the issue

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi! So everything went fine? Did you have to modify paths or anything else? I'm also thinking of deploying some Laravel app on a subdomain on shared GoDaddy cPanel hosting.